# Vertex array to a float array

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, vectormath

I am currently developing a game engine, and was asked to make a method that takes in a vertex array and outputs a float array. We have a class made for Vector3. Vector3 is a wrapper for 3 floats, x,y and z. The vertex is just a wrapper for a Vector3f. So if their is a vertex array how can i turn it into a float array. This is what i have so far

```
   public static float[] VertexArrayToFloatArray(Vertex[] vertices){
       float[] floats = new float[vertices.length];

       int i = 0;
       for (Vertex v : vertices){
           float x, y, z;
           x = v.getPosition().getX();
           y = v.getPosition().getY();
           z = v.getPosition().getZ();

           floats[i] = x;
           floats[i + 1] = y;
           floats[i + 2] = z;
       }
       System.out.println(floats);
       return floats;
   }
```

An expected output would be puting in a vertex array to make a square such as

```
Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[]{

 new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f,-0.5f,0)), //Bottom Right
 new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f,0.5f,0)), // Top Left
 new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f,0.5f,0)),  //Top Right
 new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f,-0.5f,0)) //Bottom Left
}
```

and you would get

```
{0.5f,-0.5f,0,-0.5f,0.5f,0,0.5f,0.5f,0 ,-0.5f,-0.5f,0}
```

as the result

Comment: Classes `Vertex` and `Vector3f` should provide some means to extract the value of their fields. Without seeing the structure of those classes, one can't possibly know what to do. Please try creating a [mre] to make sure others can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. In your example, you are creating an array with the size of the number of vertices from the input, but since every Vertex has 3 floats you want to create an array with triple the size of the input**

```
float[] floats = new float[vertices.length*3];
```

**2. Then you are correctly doing for loop but you are never changing the index `i`.**

That means that you are only overwriting index 0,1 and 2.
Instead of that, you need to increment the `i` by 3 (You are adding on `i`,`i+1`, and `i+2`) every loop

Something like this:

```
for (Vertex v : vertices){
           float x, y, z;
           x = v.getPosition().getX();
           y = v.getPosition().getY();
           z = v.getPosition().getZ();

           floats[i] = x;
           floats[i + 1] = y;
           floats[i + 2] = z;
           i+=3;
}
```

Or you can use `i++` which increase `i` by 1 and returns the value of `i` **BEFORE** increasing
If we then combine those 2 advise we get

```
public static float[] VertexArrayToFloatArray(Vertex[] vertices){
       float[] floats = new float[vertices.length*3];

       int i = 0;
       for (Vertex v : vertices){
           float x, y, z;
           x = v.getPosition().getX();
           y = v.getPosition().getY();
           z = v.getPosition().getZ();

           floats[i] = x;
           floats[i++] = y;
           floats[i++] = z;
       }
       System.out.println(floats);
       return floats;
   }
```